# SQL - Using a variable as the entire XQuery path in XML.value()

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

Is it possible to use a variable to define the entire XQuery path when using `.value()` on an XML field?

Using `[local-name()=sql:variable("@FilterA")]`, I can define the *filter* I want to apply as a pair of variables, but I can't get a valid syntax for the entire XQuery path to work.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @myData AS TABLE (myID INT, Parameter XML)
INSERT INTO @myData VALUES
(1, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>1</term></paramdata>'),
(2, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>5</term></paramdata>')

--This works as expected
SELECT * FROM @myData
WHERE Parameter.value('/paramdata/term=5','bit') = 1


--Two variables is possible
DECLARE @FilterA VARCHAR(255) = 'term'
DECLARE @FilterB VARCHAR(255) = '5'

SELECT * FROM @myData
WHERE Parameter.value('(/paramdata/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@FilterA")])[1]','int') = @FilterB

--but a single variable isn't
DECLARE @Filter1 VARCHAR(255) = '/paramdata/term=5'
SELECT * FROM @myData
WHERE Parameter.value('[local-name()=sql:variable("@Filter1")]','bit') = 1
```

I'm aware that casting the whole query to a string and "EXEC"-ing it should work, but this likely not suitable for the larger case where I want to apply this.

EDIT

After reading about the XY problem this question should be rephrased as:
*"is there a way to use an argument of the format `SomeNode=SomeValue` to filter on XML columns?"*

Comment: Is the structure always the same, or is this just an example?

Comment: Btw: How is this XML generated? Date values should be ISO8601 and never an ambigous culture specific string format...

Comment: More or less the same - there will always be a <paramdata/> element, but the inner nodes may vary, so date, term etc may not exist on some records. Point taken on the date values - consider this a work in progress...

Comment: If there is always the node `paramdata` why would you want to pass in the filter as `/paramdata/SomeNode=SomeValue`? Was it possible to pass in `SomeNode=SomeValue`?

Comment: Btw: This is a good question. Clearly explained. *copy'n'paste*-sample code... Worth an upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out, it is absolutely impossible to use a variable path other than with dynamic sql and `EXEC`.

But you might do something like this:

```
DECLARE @myData AS TABLE (myID INT, Parameter XML)
INSERT INTO @myData VALUES
(1, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>1</term></paramdata>'),
(2, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>5</term></paramdata>')

DECLARE @Filter1 VARCHAR(255) = 'term=5';

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(@Filter1,CHARINDEX('=',@Filter1)-1) AS NodeName
          ,RIGHT(@Filter1,CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE(@Filter1))-1) AS SearchValue
)
SELECT md.myID
      ,md.Parameter
      ,md.Parameter.value('(/paramdata/*[local-name()=sql:column("NodeName")])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY @myData AS md
```

(You can use this expression in a `WHERE`clause as well

Another approach might be this:

```
DECLARE @myData AS TABLE (myID INT, Parameter XML)
INSERT INTO @myData VALUES
(1, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>1</term></paramdata>'),
(2, '<paramdata><Date>19/06/15</Date><term>5</term></paramdata>')

DECLARE @Filter1 VARCHAR(255) = 'term=5';

WITH TheRightID AS
(
    SELECT md.myID
    FROM  @myData AS md     
    CROSS APPLY md.Parameter.nodes('/paramdata/*') AS A(Nd)
    WHERE Nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') + N'=' + Nd.value('.','nvarchar(max)')=@Filter1
)
SELECT * FROM @myData WHERE myID IN(SELECT x.myID FROM TheRightID AS x)
```

### EDIT

You might even use this to fully answer your initial question:

```
    WHERE N'/' + Nd.value('local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') 
        + N'/' +Nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') 
        + N'=' + Nd.value('.','nvarchar(max)')=@Filter1
```

### Advise

But my advise was to read [about the XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly! These solutions solve the _problem_ I have, rather than the answer I proposed (to which @Sergey has answered correctly - "nope").

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use dynamic XQuery path. The path parameter of .value() method and others is considered as string literal, not as variable.

Comment: The two-part solution seems to suggest that introducing variables in a string literal using "sql:variable()" is possible.

Comment: ... `WHERE Parameter.value('(/paramdata/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@FilterA")])[1]','int') = @FilterB` - but using a variable for the _entire_ argument is where I can't decipher the syntax required - if it is at all possible.

Comment: @calvinXS Yes, you can use "sql:variable()" for referring outer variables in expression, but you can't use variables to construct XQuery expression itself. If this were so, there would be no need for "sql:variable()" clause, because it would be possible simply concatenate: '(/paramdata/*[local-name()=' + @F‌​ilterA + ')])[1]'

Comment: @Sergey, fully ACK This answer is a bit to short for a *good* answer, but there is not much more to say... +1 from my side